# how to get value of select field in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am using `react-hook-form` with material UI.On button click I want to get my `autocomplete select` box value. currently it is taking `label` as a `value` I need year should be a value

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-nt4kh

when I select `{ title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },` the value should be `1972`. currently on button click is shows `The Godfather` why ?

```
<Autocomplete
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            inputRef={register}
            label={"Resolution Code"}
            variant="outlined"
            name={"resolutionCode"}
            fullWidth
          />
        )}
```

[image]
          />

Comment: `getOptionLabel={option => option.title}` here you use option.title as label so it shows "Godfather" in select box. You want to show year instead?

Comment: You can set the value of option using the `value` attribute. See - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/binding/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the related API document [here](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

```js
// From
getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
// To
getOptionLabel={option => option.year.toString()}
```

Update:
option displayed and value selected using different attributes

```js
renderOption={params => (
  <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle1" component="h2">
    {params.title}
  </Typography>
)}
getOptionLabel={option => option.year.toString()}
```

**getOptionLabel**

> Used to determine the string value for a given option. It's used to fill the input (and the list box options if renderOption is not provided).

**renderOption**

> function(option: T, state: object) => ReactNode
>   option: The option to render.
>   state: The state of the component.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Get Started]

Addition:
Since the question is like something below

> when I select { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 }, the value should be 1972. currently on button click is shows The Godfather why ?

I guess the above answer is handling that demand.

If you simply want the value for your console, just find it from your data since the select option should not be duplicated.

```js
  const onSubmit = data => {
    const temp = top100Films.find(x => x.title === data.resolutionCode);
    const value = temp ? temp.year.toString() : "";
    console.log(value);
  };
```

Comment: How to get the year as value but still show title in the select box

Comment: we are doing something wrong ...!! after select "on disable it should show godfather" but value will be `1972`

Comment: this solution doesn't works...!! :( after select it it shows `1972` in select box

Comment: I don't really sure about what you want to do.

Comment: @keikai wait I will explain more ..actually I want to show title to the users .but whenever they selected any title it's year will be the value

Comment: In your example first time title are displayed after selection value is saved ..but in select box value is also display(which is wrong)

Comment: thanks for help .see after a long timw i found the solution https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-v24jk

Comment: @user944513 nice job

Comment: still confused to how to set `initial value`..!!