# Material UI Autocomplete Component with Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, redux-form

The problem is as follows:
Im using Material Ui Autocomplete Component (https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) in a Redux-Form.
The Autocomplete Component is provided with a list of options where each option is an object, containing "@id" property, and some other human-readable properties, depending on the resource.

The component is told via "getOptionLabel" prop to generate options labels from the readable properties. After typing/selecting any label from the list provided by Autocomplete, the label is converted to input value, and thus stored in the store as value of the redux-form field.

**Problem: Autocomplete component should provide redux-form with value different than the one present on label.** 
However as of yet I'm unable to do it in some simple way. I'm sure its possible, but at this point I'm also sure that I don't understand which combination of component props would handle such scenario.

What I managed to do so far is using ChildContextTypes on the form itself, to pass the redux-form change dispatch (https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-change-form-string-field-string-value-any-code-) to the Autocomplete component. 
This way, i can specify in the Autocomplete component an onChange event, that will handle switching the values.

Current code:

```
export class AutocompleteField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            options: [],
            selectedValue: null,
        };
    }
  static contextTypes = {
        changeFieldValue: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
  componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchLabels();
    }
  fetchLabels() {
       // call api, setState({options: resulst of api call })
    }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (!this.state.selectedValue) {
            return;
        }
        this.context.changeFieldValue(`example_field`, `${this.state.selectedValue["@id"]}`);
    }
  changeLabelToIRI(event, value) {
        this.setState({selectedValue: value})
    }
  getOptionsLabels(option) {
    // format option labels according to resource
  }
  render() {
      const {input} = this.props;
      return(
        <Autocomplete
                    options={this.state.options}
                    getOptionLabel={option => (this.getOptionLabels(option))}
                    onChange={(event, value ) => this.changeLabelToIRI(event, value)}
                    renderInput={params => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            {...input}
                        />
                    )}
                />
      )
  }
}
```

Could really use some tips on how to make it simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105933/how-to-get-value-of-select-field-in-react/60106099#60106099

Comment: If you want some multi-selection component which can achieve `{value, label}` selection, you can use lib: `react-select`